# Getting relative order of different command line options using clap & structopt

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, clap, structopt

## The Problem

I have a command that takes different options and the *relative order* of those options is important to the semantics of the command. For example, in `command --config A --some-option --config-file B --random-option --config C --another-option --more-options --config-file D`, the relative order of `A, B, C, D` is important as it affects the meaning of the command.

If I just define the options as follows:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
pub struct Command {
    #[structopt(long = "config")]
    configs: Vec<String>,

    #[structopt(long = "config-file")]
    config_files: Vec<String>,
}
```

Then I will get two vectors, `configs = [A, C]` and `config_files = [B, D]` but the relative order between the elements in `configs` and `config_files` has been lost.

## Ideas

#### Custom Parse Functions

The idea was to provide a custom parse function and use a counter to record the indexes as each option was parsed. Unfortunately, the parsing functions are not called in the original order defined by the command.

```rust
fn get_next_atomic_int() -> usize {
    static ATOMIC_COUNTER: Lazy<AtomicUsize> = Lazy::new(|| AtomicUsize::new(0));
    ATOMIC_COUNTER.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed)
}

fn parse_passthrough_string_ordered(arg: &str) -> (String, usize) {
    (arg.to_owned(), get_next_atomic_int())
}

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
#[structopt(name = "command"]
pub struct Command {
    #[structopt(long = "config-file", parse(from_str = parse_passthrough_string_ordered))]
    config_files: Vec<(String, usize)>,
    
    #[structopt(short = "c", long = "config", parse(from_str = parse_passthrough_string_ordered))]
    configs: Vec<(String, usize)>,
}
```

#### Aliases

I can add an alias for the option, like so:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
pub struct Command {
    #[structopt(long = "config", visible_alias = "config-file")]
    configs: Vec<String>,
}
```

There are two problems with this approach:

- I need a way to distinguish whether an option was passed via `--config` or `--config-file` (it's not always possible to figure out how a value was passed just by inspecting the value).
- I cannot provide a short option for the visible alias.

#### Same Vector, Multiple Options

The other idea was to attach multiple `structopt` directives, so that the same underlying vector would be used for both options. Unfortunately, it does not work - `structopt` only uses the last directive. Something like:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Config {
    File(String),
    Literal(String),
}

fn parse_config_literal(arg: &str) -> Config {
    Config::Literal(arg.to_owned())
}

fn parse_config_file(arg: &str) -> Config {
    Config::File(arg.to_owned())
}

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
#[structopt(name = "example")]
struct Opt {
    #[structopt(long = "--config-file", parse(from_str = parse_config_file))]
    #[structopt(short = "-c", long = "--config", parse(from_str = parse_config_literal))]
    options: Vec<Config>,
}
```

#### Recovering the Order

I could try to recover the original order by searching for the parsed values. But this means I would have to duplicate quite a bit of parsing logic (e.g., need to support passing `--config=X`, `--config X`, need to handle `X` appearing as input to another option, etc).

I'd rather just have a way to reliably get the original rather rather than lose the order and try to recover it in a possibly fragile way.

Comment: Does every `--config` option need to be followed by a `--config-file`? If so, can you define that `--config` needs two parameters, and skip the `--config-file` part?

Comment: @JohnBayko: Nope, it's just an example. There are no constraints on how many such options appear (e.g., only `--config`, only `--config-file`, both or even intermixed with other ones). For example, `--config X --some-other-option --config Y --another --verbose --config-file Z --debug --config M`.

Answer (score 3):

As outlined by [@TeXitoi](https://github.com/TeXitoi), I missed the `ArgMatches::indices_of()` function which gives us the required information.

```
use structopt::StructOpt;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Config {
    File(String),
    Literal(String),
}

fn parse_config_literal(arg: &str) -> Config {
    Config::Literal(arg.to_owned())
}

fn parse_config_file(arg: &str) -> Config {
    Config::File(arg.to_owned())
}

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
#[structopt(name = "example")]
struct Opt {
    #[structopt(short = "c", long = "config", parse(from_str = parse_config_literal))]
    configs: Vec<Config>,

    #[structopt(long = "config-file", parse(from_str = parse_config_file))]
    config_files: Vec<Config>,
}

fn with_indices<'a, I: IntoIterator + 'a>(
    collection: I,
    name: &str,
    matches: &'a structopt::clap::ArgMatches,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, I::Item)> + 'a {
    matches
        .indices_of(name)
        .into_iter()
        .flatten()
        .zip(collection)
}

fn main() {
    let args = vec!["example", "--config", "A", "--config-file", "B", "--config", "C", "--config-file", "D"];
    
    let clap = Opt::clap();
    let matches = clap.get_matches_from(args);
    let opt = Opt::from_clap(&matches);

    println!("configs:");
    for (i, c) in with_indices(&opt.configs, "configs", &matches) {
        println!("{}: {:#?}", i, c);
    }

    println!("\nconfig-files:");
    for (i, c) in with_indices(&opt.config_files, "config-files", &matches) {
        println!("{}: {:#?}", i, c);
    }
}
```